# Is it possible to know the time a play application has been started?

Tags: playframework

I'd like to display the time at which a Play!Framework application has been started (either `play run`, `play dist`, etc).

I took a look at the Play package without any luck. Maybe I can find it in some deeper package outside Play (in Java ?).

Something like :

```
System.out.println("This project has been started at :");
System.out.println(play.Play.applicaton().startTime()); // Of course this doesn't work.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it for one of my projects :

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public static Date startTime;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        super.onStart(app);
        startTime = new Date();
        Logger.info("Application ready...");
    }

}
```

The value is then accessible wherever you want by calling `Global.startTime`.

There might be a better solution, but I couldn't find it.
Maybe by checking the date of creation of `RUNNING_PID` but that would work only with `play start`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onLoadConfig` in `Global.java` and add the current time as a configuration value.

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

  public Configuration onLoadConfig(Configuration config, java.io.File path, java.lang.ClassLoader classloader) {
    return config.underlying().withValue("start-time", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef((new Date()).toString));
  }

}
```

Of course you can customize the date representation to whatever you prefer.  This makes `start-time` a configuration key accessible just like any other config value in your application.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. your `return` line returns a `Config` but a `Configuration` is expected. I tried to return a `new Configuration({your line})` but the value is null when accessing it.